# AWS WAF : You have used none or multiple values for a field that requires exactly one value

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, bots, amazon-waf

#### Problem

Cannot implement AWS-defined custom JSON rule for AWS WAF.
I am following [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/waf-bot-control-example-user-agent-exception.html), and I don't understand how I am exceeding the values. Rule #2 I was able to apply, but I need to be able to apply the count rule as well.

##### Error

```
Error reason: You have used none or multiple values for a field that requires exactly one value., field: RULE, parameter: Rule
```

```
{
  "Name": "AWSBotControl-SignalOverride",
  "Priority": 5,
  "Statement": {
    "ManagedRuleGroupStatement": {
      "VendorName": "AWS",
      "Name": "AWSManagedRulesBotControlRuleSet",
      "RuleActionOverrides": [
        {
          "Action": "Count",
          "OverrideAction": { "Count": {} }, // Use this if specific configuration for count is needed.
          "Name": "SignalNonBrowserUserAgent"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "VisibilityConfig": {
    "SampledRequestsEnabled": true,
    "CloudWatchMetricsEnabled": true,
    "MetricName": "AWSBotControl-SignalOverride"
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This seems to have worked for me. It's an inherent optional setting at the bottom of the BotControl rules for the WebACL.

[image: Override rule group action]

Use this in combination with a rule for throttling and you can prevent non-browsers agents from being blocked by default.